# Reduce size of Spark Dataframe by selecting only every n th element with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I v got an `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataframe = [t: double, S: long]`

[image]

Now I want to reduce the *Dataframe* by every 2nd element, with `val n=2`

Result should be

[image]

How would u solve this problem?

I tried it by inserting a third column and using modulo, but I couldn’t solve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you want to keep every `nth` element from your `dataframe` and remove every other row. Assuming `t` is not your `row index`,add an index row and then filter it by:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val n = 2
val filteredDF = df.withColumn("index", row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id))).filter($"index" % n === 0)
```

Comment: Thank u very much! That’s exactly what I was trying to achieve!